# On/Off Django app at specific date

Tags: django

I am creating a Django Project(which has a lot of Django apps in it) and I need some help.
I only need to add a small feature.
The admin will decide a date upto which the app will be shown to all.
I want the app to automatically redirect all users to a specific page after the mentioned date.
How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple middleware (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/) will resolve your requirement. Something like this:

```
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class OnOffMiddleware(object,):
    def process_request(request):
        if datetime.datetime.now() > settings.SHOW_DATE:
            # Should redirect people
            return HttpResponseRedirect('redirect to a specifc page')
        else: 
            # Continue as usual
            return None
```

Put the above in a module somewhere in your project and add it to the top of your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware).

Comment: I fully agree with Serafeim. You can also do same thing using django Decorator.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question the django project has a lot of apps in it.
Can I know currently which app the user is on, so that I can redirect him to page corresponding to that app with the help of middleware?

Comment: What do you mean "app the user is on". You couls find which path/view the user wants to visit (through request). If you've seperated your urls per app (using a common path for each app) then you could check that path in process_request and redirect to different places.